# Matlab Neural Network for Classes - Unseen Data

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Say I create a neural network to separate classes:

```
X1; %Some data in Class 1 100x2
X2; %Some data in Class 2 100x2

classInput = [X1;X2];
negative = zeros(N, 1);
positive = ones(N,1);
classTarget = [positive negative; negative positive]; 

net = feedforwardnet(20);
net = configure(net, classInput, classTarget);
net = train(net, classInput, classTarget);
%output of training data
output = net(classInput);
```

I can plot the classes and they are correctly separated:

```
figure();
hold on
style = {'ro' 'bx'};

for i=1:(2*N)
    plot(classInput(i,1),classInput(i,2), style{round(output(i,1))+1});
end
```

However, how can I apply the network that's just been trained to unseen data? There must be a model which is generated by the network that can be applied to new data?

EDIT: Using sim:

Once the network is trained, if I use sim on the training data:

```
[Z,Xf,Af] = sim(net,classInput);
```

The result is as expected. But this only works if the input is of the same size. If for example I want to evalute an individual data point:

```
[Z1,Xf,Af] = sim(net,[1,2]);
```

size(Z) == size(Z1), but this clearly doesn't make sense? Surely I can evaluate a single data point?

Comment: That's weird... perhaps replicate the matrix so that it's the same size as your `classInput`, then just pull out one of the results... so do something like: `[Z1,Xf,Af] = sim(net,repmat([1,2], size(classInput,1), 1));`, then look at `Z1(1)` for your answer, but that's totally unnecessary IMO... I'll have to investigate.

Comment: That does not seem to work - a large matrix is produced but none of the values correlate to the expected output, even when I use a seen data point as the data point.

Comment: @rayryeng I have found the error, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the OP,

I had assumed that the rows of the input matrices were the data samples and the columns were the "categories", this is the other way around. Transposing the matrices before inputting them to the train() function fixes this.